# Chaining methods with delays in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to make this piece of code more efficient.

```
(function() { 
    sc = angular.element('tbody').scope(); sc.draft.resetRoster(); sc.$apply(); 
    setTimeout(function() {
        sc.draft.rosterAdd({id: "12921", salary: 10600, position: "P"});sc.draft.rosterAdd({id: "12123", salary: 2900, position: "C"});sc.draft.rosterAdd({id: "5435", salary: 3800, position: "1B"});sc.draft.rosterAdd({id: "12562", salary: 2400, position: "2B"});sc.draft.rosterAdd({id: "38321", salary: 3100, position: "3B"});sc.draft.rosterAdd({id: "6319", salary: 2400, position: "SS"});sc.draft.rosterAdd({id: "5204", salary: 3200, position: "OF"});sc.draft.rosterAdd({id: "5222", salary: 2500, position: "OF"});sc.draft.rosterAdd({id: "12462", salary: 2600, position: "OF"});
    }, 3000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelector('#enterButton').click();
    }, 6000);
})();
```

I'm not entirely familiar with Angular (actually not at all). I'm trying to create a client-side script that interacts with Angular. There's 5 total statements here that I'm trying to condense into as little code as possible. Before the first `setTimeout` gets triggered in 3,000ms, I need this to run: `sc = angular.element('tbody').scope(); sc.draft.resetRoster(); sc.$apply();`

After 3,000ms, the first `setTimeout` runs. Roughly 6,000ms (assuming there's roughly a ~3,000ms gap between the first `setTimeout` and second `setTimeout`) I need the second `setTimeout` to execute.

Is there a better way to put together this function? Less code? Better sequencing of how I'm handling `setTimeout` in general?

Comment: You'll probably want to look into Promises, specifically [Angular's implementation of $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Comment: As an aside, I would defer to readability over less code and let your minimizer handle the latter optimization. I think promises are definitely the way to go for achieving your sequencing with readability.

Comment: You probably also want to use the angular $timeout function instead of setTimeout or your bindings won't update properly. $timeout also returns promises, which should make cleaning up the code even easier.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `setTimeout` use angular service `$timeout` which functions similarly but returns a `promise` that will be resolved after the specified amount of time has elapsed, and also calls `$apply`. So in your case:

```
$timeout(function () { ... }, 3000).then(function () {
    //after the first timeout we set another one and return its promise
    $timeout(function () { ... }, 3000);
});
```

This way you get rid off the mental arithmetic and you can just set the time you want to wait after the last timeout has elapsed, without nesting timeout functions.

Comment: _we set another one and return its promise_ - You don't return it.